# Sample SSO webapplication does not work in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured the sample travelocity.com webapp to work with saml2 SSO following link [configure SSO web app](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0)

But when i try to login using account i get following error message on browser 
[image: See snapshot]

Here is what i get in logs:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-03-10 21:06:26,835]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Signature validation for Authentication Request failed. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor}
```

After again i tried without restart of server i got this error:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-03-10 20:30:51,261] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
```

I am not sure what is wrong. I have also installed latest service pack . I am using **wso2is-5.0.0**

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

This same web application is working fine with WSO2IS.  I have already tried out it..Details can be found from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/) as well

According to the error, it says  `Signature validation for Authentication Request failed` it means that SAML2 Auth request that is sent by Web application has been signed and WSO2IS tries to validate the signature of it. WSO2IS does not validate the signature by default, you may have probably tick on following configuration in the SAML2 SSO configuration.

`Enable Signature Validation in Authentication Requests and Logout Requests`

Please verify it and un-tick it and see.

If you want to really validate the signature of SAML2 Auth requests, you need to tick it. Then you must chose the proper  `Certificate Alias` value from the combo box.  Please note proper value is NOT the `wso2carbon.cert`. Proper value is  `wso2carbon`.  Then it would work for you.

Second error may be related to browser cache,  just clear the browser cache and try out.. (or open new browser)

Comment: @asela, I had the same issue, and I successfully configured it according to your answer on _WSO2IS 5.1.0_, but I can't configure _WSO2IS-4.6.0_. In 4.6.0 there is only `wso2carbon` value in **Certificate Alias** dropdown, so it shoud work, right? I even tried to modify `IdPCertAlias` in `authenticators.xml` with no luck. Could you point me what should I do to make it work on _4.6.0_ as well?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is a mismatch in the keystores.

Just copy

```
$WSO2IS/repository/resources/security/keystore.jks
```

To

```
$TOMCAT/saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com/WEB-INF/classes
```

This way, both keystores are the same. Restart Tomcat and it should work fine.

Comment: Copying a keystore is asking for it getting out of synch later. Instead you can simply tell Java where the keystore is via Java system options so it references the right one. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/csec_ssl_jsp_start_server.html